# ATMEGA2561 WINC1500 Driver implementation SPI problem

Tags: spi, atmega, atmel

I am trying to implement the WINC1500 MLA Driver to work with the ATMEGA2561 MCU and I have written my driver code and it's stuck on the line "while((SPSR & (1 << SPIF)) == 0);" in the m2mStub_SpiTxRx function.

I have no idea why it's not progressing through. I'm using the jumpstart ImageCraft IDE for this project.

**Here's the implementation of it**

```
void m2mStub_SpiTxRx(uint8_t *p_txBuf,
                     uint16_t txLen,
                     uint8_t *p_rxBuf,
                     uint16_t rxLen)
{
    uint16_t byteCount;
    uint16_t i;

    // Calculate the number of clock cycles necessary, this implies a full-duplex SPI.
    byteCount = (txLen >= rxLen) ? txLen : rxLen;
    DEBUGOUTF("Calculate the number of clock cycles\n");

    DEBUGOUTF("byteCount %d", byteCount, "\n");
    DEBUGOUTF("txLen %d", txLen, "\n");
    DEBUGOUTF("rxLen %d", rxLen, "\n");

    // Read / Transmit.
    for (i = 0; i < byteCount; ++i)
    {
        // Wait for transmitter to be ready. (This is causing the entire thing to crash)
        while((SPSR & (1 << SPIF)) == 0);

        // Transmit.
        if (txLen > 0)
        {
            // Send data from the transmit buffer.
            SPDR = (*p_txBuf++);
            --txLen;
        }
        else
        {
            // No more Tx data to send, just send something to keep clock active.
            SPDR = 0x00U;
        }

        // Wait for transfer to finish.
        while((SPSR & (1 << SPIF)) == 0);

        // Send dummy data to slave, so we can read something from it.
        SPDR = 0x00U;

        // Wait for transfer to finish.
        while((SPSR & (1 << SPIF)) == 0);

        // Read or throw away data from the slave as required.
        if (rxLen > 0)
        {
            *p_rxBuf++ = SPDR;
            --rxLen;
        }
        else
        {
            // Clear the registers
            volatile uint8_t reg_clear = 0U;
            reg_clear = SPDR;
            (void)reg_clear;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well you say "causing the entire thing to _crash_" but the rest of your description sounds more like a hang than a crash. And that would be expected if the transmitter simply isn't ready, or not connected correctly, or something like that! I'd say you should start by debugging your SPI connectivity in general

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to say for sure, but my assumption is that your SPI connection is not set up correctly.

In particular, I guess you forgot to set `/SS` as output, same as [this problem](https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/630438#comment-630438) or [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171494/what-is-holding-the-ss-pin-high-in-spi-master-mode-on-avrs).

In the datasheet it says:

> Master Mode When the SPI is configured as a master (MSTR in SPCR is
>   set), the user can determine the direction of the SS pin.
>
> **If SS is configured as an output, the pin is a general output pin
>   which does not affect the SPI system. Typically, the pin will be
>   driving the SS pin of the SPI slave.**
>
> **If SS is configured as an input, it must be held high to ensure Master
>   SPI operation.** If the SS pin is driven low by peripheral circuitry
>   when the SPI is configured as a master with the SS pin defined as an
>   input, the SPI system interprets this as another master selecting the
>   SPI as a slave and starting to send data to it. To avoid bus
>   contention, the SPI system takes the following actions:
>
> 1. The MSTR bit in SPCR is cleared and the SPI system becomes a slave. As a result of the SPI becoming a slave, the MOSI and SCK pins become
>      inputs.
> 2. The SPIF flag in SPSR is set, and if the SPI interrupt is enabled, and the I-bit in SREG is set, the interrupt routine will be executed.
>
> Thus, when interrupt-driven SPI transmission is used in master mode,
>   and there exists a possibility that SS is driven low, the interrupt
>   should always check that the MSTR bit is still set. If the MSTR bit
>   has been cleared by a slave select, it must be set by the user to
>   re-enable SPI master mode.

So, you just need to configure the `/SS` pin as output and set to high in your init code, this should solve your problem:

```cpp
DDRB |= (1 << PB0); // Set /SS (PB0) as output
PORTB |= (1 << PB0); // Set /SS (PB0) high
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have configured the SS Pin as an output as you mentioned and set it to high but it still hasn't solved the problem